# How to know that angular completed all processing and rendering

Tags: javascript, angularjs, interceptor, progress

I need to stop progress bar.
If I have several `http` request, how can i know when all threads completed, and all responses are rendered.
I tried to use `$httpProvider.interceptors` on response, but i can not know whether this is the last `http` response or not. And also you can not know when this last response will be rendered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can track the pending request by `http.pendingRequests` in your interceptor like

```
angular.module('myApp').factory('myHttpResponseInterceptor', function($q, $location, $injector, $rootScope){
    var _http = null;

    return {
        request: function(config){
            $rootScope.$broadcast("loader_show");
            return config;
        },
        response: function(response){
            _http = _http || $injector.get('$http');
            if(_http.pendingRequests.length < 1){
                $rootScope.$broadcast("loader_hide");
            }
            return response;
        },
        responseError: function (response) {
            _http = _http || $injector.get('$http');
            if(_http.pendingRequests.length < 1){
                $rootScope.$broadcast("loader_hide");
            }
            console.log("response rejected in interceptor");
            return $q.reject(response);
        }
    };
});
```

I have used this in my project and it works just fine.

Hope it helps you too.

Comment: Sank You  i also resolve it by MySelf:  $rootScope.httpRequestCnt++; in request AND  $rootScope.httpRequestCnt--; in  response. But you'r decision is beter

Answer (score 0):

You can use a module like [angular-busy](https://github.com/cgross/angular-busy) or [ngProgress](http://victorbjelkholm.github.io/ngProgress/) to do the same.